# Extending abstract classes in java

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, subclass, superclass

I have two classes, say a car and a truck, that are sub classes of an abstract class vehicle. I have a segment of code that is common between both truck and car so to save code space I want to put the method into the super class that way I can call it in the subclass. I am having trouble with this. Here is the code I got.

```
public class TruckShape extends VehicleShape    //The code here is the same for both classes
{
   public TruckShape(int x, int y, int width)
   {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.width = width;
   }
   .
   .
   .
   public void translate(int dx, int dy)
   {
      x += dx;
      y += dy;
   }
}
```

This code exists in both the Truck and Car class. For some reason, whenever I try to put it in the super class, it compiles, but when I drag the car (with the mouse) to translate it, it doesn't move at all. Here's what I got:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public abstract class VehicleShape implements SceneShape
{  
   .
   .
   .

   public void translate(int dx, int dy)
   {
      x += dx;
      y += dy;
   }

   private boolean selected;
   private int x;
   private int y;
}
```

When I place the translate method into the abstract super class and remove it from the subclass, the program doesn't work right. I tried creating a super class constructor and initializing x and y there instead of in the subclass to see if maybe that's why translate wasn't working, but that did nothing. Is there a way for me to get a method that is shared between 2 sub classes working in an abstract super class? That way, the program works and there is not duplicate code. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the variables in your abstract class are `private`. That means they can't be seen by the extending subclass. Try making them `protected`.

Comment: Moreover, delete the `x` and `y` member variables from your `CarShape` and `TruckShape` classes (these are presumed based on your description, though you didn't show them).  Allow the subclasses to use the superclass's `x` and `y`.

Comment: you should be more precise about "the program doesn't work right". what do you mean? can you put some example output and some more code to understand the problem you're having?

Comment: Do you perhaps have multiple copies of `x` and `y` (in the superclass and in the subclasses)? The reason it looks like you do is that if `x` is private, the line `this.x = x` shouldn't compile (unless `this.x` refers to something else).

Comment: So I made the x and y in the superclass `protected` and deleted the x and y variables in the `CarShape` and `TruckShape` class and it worked. Is it a bad programming practice to use the `protected` access specifier? I have been told by my professors that we should always make things private that protected is bad.

Comment: *Update* I emailed my professor and he said that we are NOT allowed to use the `protected` access specifier. How could I get around this? I tried it with private x and y and it wouldn't compile.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer questions about your abstract superclass if we could _see_ it.  For instance, does it have public methods like `getX` and `setX`?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to include the changes you've tried, and especially your professor's ruling on `protected` fields.